# Which JS framework works well with openlayers?

Tags: angularjs, reactjs, vue.js, openlayers

I'm looking to implement a front end framework (e.g. react, Vue, angular) however I will need to use openlayers.

Which front end framework would recommend that works well with openlayers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would not make a choice just because i have to use openlayers. However, you could check in google openlayer + `<framework/library>`

For instance, for react you have this one:
https://github.com/allenhwkim/react-openlayers

Comment: Have you got experience working with openlayers in a js framework? If so what did you use and how did it go? My app will be heavy on using openlayers, so it's a big factor for me

Comment: i mean, i did a huge react app with leaflet for instance. What you should do, if the biggest thing in your app is on openlayers, is to check if there are libraries that work well with openlayers + framework you want. Keep in mind something: you could have performance problems with this kind of libraries. 

So if performance is critical in your app, or if you are going to render thousands of points at the same time, try to decouple to vanilla js the map part and do whatever you need with react, vue or angular. Just an advice of someone that had performance problems with that kind of libraries